# Sensitive border area between MouseEnter and MouseLeave events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouseevent

I have a `PictureBox` control on my form for which I have written two events for `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`. On `MouseEnter` anther `PictureBox` enters the form and stands beside the original and with `MouseLeave` the second `PictureBox` goes way.

All works fine. Except when the cursor is on the original `PictureBox`’s border area the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events are repeatedly run. So the second image enters and leaves the form until the cursor is taken away. This makes a strange sight.

How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: Sounds as if the 2nd pb pushes the 1st one away or something changes its size. does it happen at all sides? what border do you have? can you show the code for enter and leave?

Comment: @TaW This is correct! Please post this as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border area can be tricky, especially when you want to trigger something the might influence it even if it is only by a few pixels..

One classic situation is when you want to resize or move a control by clicking an dragging it at its border. Unless you use the internal calls and simply code mouseenter, -leave, -move, -down and -up you may well end up with e.g. moving the control away from the mouse and thereby triggering another leave event.

This often occurs only at one set of borders, like left&top or right&bottom.

You need to check you code for any such influences, like the new `PictureBox` pushing the old one away by a few pixels or a resize that makes it smaller; even one pixel can lead to the effect you see..

Answer (score 0):

If the MouseEnter event is triggering a border to be drawn, or the size of the first PictureBox to change in any way, that can cause the effect you describe.

You could add a check against the mouse coordinates in MouseEnter to ensure that the mouse pointer gets far enough into the control's interior before the event fires.  That would prevent an instant firing of the Leave event.

Comment: The `MouseEnter` event does not trigger anything. It's for a normal PictureBox control. It's when the user holds the mouse on the border of this picturebox that it goes crazy.